# Sort array of objects on multiple enum values

Tags: javascript, arrays, sorting

I have an array of objects containing a property on either of following enum values that I'm trying to sort in following order:

- TYPE1
- TYPE1
- TYPE2
- TYPE2
- TYPE2
- TYPE3

I tried to,

```
function sort(objA, objB)
{
   if (objA.field == TYPE1 || objB.field == TYPE1) return 1;
   if (objA.field == TYPE2 || objB.field == TYPE2) return -1;
   return 0;
}
```

..but nothing works correctly.